# is there any other method to traverse the list and build widgets inside build() other than listview.builder() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have an list of strings, and I need to display it in Text() widget.So i can use listview.builder() and traverse it by index and build Text() widget.
Is there any other ways to do the same?

```
class Ask extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ask({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AskState createState() => _AskState();
}

class _AskState extends State<Ask> {
  List<String> msg=['hi','hey','bye','how are you?'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(title:Text("Show")),
      body:ListView.builder(
        itemCount: msg.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
             return Text(
               '${msg[index]}'
             );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes there are couple of ways but may I know whats the issue with listview.builder? so that I can help better

Comment: list view works fine, but say i need to have listview inside an column theni would need to wrap with expanded(says take entire space which pushes my other vwidgets to the end of screen) or container( but need to give a specific height)

So just wanted to know any other ways that does the same thing
Also we cant use loops inside the build right so could to mention other ways of doing it

Comment: ofcourse you could use for loops let me add the answer

Comment: change `msg[index]` to `$msg[index]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three ways I am aware of showing a list of Widgets without using ListView.builder which you can directly use in a column without having to worry about a fixed vertical size because this type of List only takes as much height as the combined height of the children.

1. Using a for loop inside a column

```
 for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) Text(msg[i]),
```

2. Using List generate with the spread operator(...)

```
  ...List.generate(msg.length, (index) => Text(msg[index])).toList(),
```

3. mapping a list of type < T > to Widget

```
 ...msg.map((e) => Text(e)).toList()
```

Note: You may get overlow error if the widget size increases so make sure to put your column in SingleChildScrollView which makes your column scrollable.

Comment: thanks, but I have an doubt in 1st option:
If I place the for loop inside the column() it throws an error right? since it doesnt have an property or attribute for... so where should the for loop?

Comment: no, it should work I just tried these all three methods in dartpad and posted it

Comment: may I know what error your are getting? make sure if you use a for loop in a column you cannot have "{}"